# Spring security unable to prevent forward to the previous page/j_spring_security_check after successful login?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I would like to prevent spring security from forwarding to the default "j_spring_security_check" after successful login,instead after successful login I would like to forward to custom welcome page "/auth/welcome.jsp" , attempted 2 approaches:

**Diagram of my desired flow:**

[image]

**Approach # 1 (used xml configuration)**

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

<display-name>Toyota Relocation App</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!--  load spring security -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,/WEB-INF/security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**security.xml:**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- spring security should ignore "/" & "/resources/**" paths -->
    <http pattern="/" security="none" auto-config="true"
        use-expressions="true" />
    <http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" auto-config="true"
        use-expressions="true" />
    <!-- spring security configuration -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/auth**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

        <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
            username-parameter="emailInputField" password-parameter="pinInputField"
            default-target-url="/auth/welcome" always-use-default-target="true" />

        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    </http>

    <!-- user accounts -->
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="naim@test.com" password="12345" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

**login.jsp: (relevant snippet)**

```
<div class="mycontent">
            <div id="logo_div">
                    <img src="resources/images/01_toyota_logo_small.png">
            </div>
                <div class="login_form_wrapper">

                <c:if test="${not empty error}">
            <div class="error">${error}</div>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
            <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
        </c:if>

                    <!-- content-->
                    <form name='loginForm' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>

                    <!-- <FORM name='loginForm' action="auth" method="post">-->
                        <ul class="mylistview" data-role="listview">
                            <li>
                                <div><img id="email_input_icon" src="resources/images/01_login_email_icon_small.png"></div><div id="email_input" ><input name="emailInputField"" id="email_input_field" type="email" data-role="none" /></div></li>
                            <li>
                                <div><img id="pin_input_icon"src="resources/images/01_login_password_icon_small.png"></div><div id="pin_input" ><input name="pinInputField" id="pin_input_field" type="password" data-role="none" /></div></li>
                            <li>
                                <div id="login_button">
                                    <button id="login" class="button" type="submit">LOGIN</button>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    </FORM>
                </div>
```

**HomeController:**

```
package com.xyz.thedallasapp_poc;

//removed imports

@Controller
public class HomeControler {

    public HomeControler() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /* serves the login landing/home page view*/
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {

        return "login";
    }

    /*process login request from login view */
    @RequestMapping (value="/login**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView processLogin(
            @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
            @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

        model.addObject("previousView", "/login");

        if (error != null) {
            model.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");
        }

        if (logout != null) {
            model.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
        }
        model.setViewName("login");

        return model;

    }

  /* forward /auth/welcome request to /auth/welcome.jsp*/
    @RequestMapping(value = "/auth/welcome")
    public ModelAndView authWelcome() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        //if reffer is /login than view is auth/welcome 
        //else view is reffer 
        model.setViewName("/auth/welcome");

        return model;

    }

}//end controller
```

**Result:**

Successful authentication & failure happen correctly, however I'm forwarded "j_spring_security_check" view which after careful inspection is actually the previous view/page with a new URL , instead of /auth/welcome.jsp view.

The logs have no error.

**Approach # 2 (used xml configuration & implemented AuthenticationSuccessHandler )**

I implemented AuthenticationSuccessHandler in order to redirect to "auth/welcome.jsp after successful login.

**The web.xml, HomeController.java are not changed compared to approach #1.**

**spring.xml:**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- spring security should ignore "/" & "/resources/**" paths -->
    <http pattern="/" security="none" auto-config="true"
        use-expressions="true" />
    <http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" auto-config="true"
        use-expressions="true" />
    <!-- spring security configuration -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/auth**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

        <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
            username-parameter="emailInputField" password-parameter="pinInputField"
            default-target-url="/auth/welcome" always-use-default-target="true" 
            authentication-success-handler-ref="myAuthSuccessHandler"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    </http>

    <!-- user accounts -->
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="naim@test.com" password="12345" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

       <!--  custom bean used to override spring security page redirection after successful authentication -->
      <beans:bean id="myAuthSuccessHandler"
        class="com.hitachi.thedallasapp_poc.security.MyAuthSuccessHandler" />
</beans:beans>
```

**MyAuthSuccessHandler: **

```
package com.hitachi.thedallasapp_poc.security;

//removed imports 

public class MyAuthSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {



        private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("Class onAuthenticationSuccess request: "+request.getRequestURL());
            System.out.println("Class onAuthenticationSuccess response status: "+response.getStatus());
            handle(request, response, authentication);
            clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
        }

        protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, 
          HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
            String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(authentication,request);

            if (response.isCommitted()) {

                return;
            }

            System.out.println("Class onAuthenticationSuccess  ,request.getContextPath(): " + request.getContextPath());
            System.out.println("Class onAuthenticationSuccess  ,targetUrl: " + targetUrl);

            redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);


        }

        /** check the Role of the user that was granted access, based on the role redirect to success page  */
        protected String determineTargetUrl(Authentication authentication, HttpServletRequest request) {
            boolean isUser = false;
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
            String redirectURL = null; 
            for (GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : authorities) {

                if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_USER")) {

                    System.out.println("Class  MyAuthSuccessHandler, grantedAuthority.getAuthority():" +grantedAuthority.getAuthority());
                    isUser = true;
                    break;
                } 
            }//end for 

            //if user is USER_ROLE redirect to "/auth/welcome"
            if (isUser) {

                System.out.println("Class  MyAuthSuccessHandler, request.getRequestURL():" +request.getRequestURL().toString());
                redirectURL =  "/auth/welcome";
            }  
            //else redirect to default
            else
            {
                redirectURL = request.getRequestURL().toString();
            }

            return redirectURL;
        }

        protected void clearAuthenticationAttributes(HttpServletRequest request) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            if (session == null) {
                return;
            }
            session.removeAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);
        }

        public void setRedirectStrategy(RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy) {
            this.redirectStrategy = redirectStrategy;
        }
        protected RedirectStrategy getRedirectStrategy() {
            return redirectStrategy;
        }

}//end class MyAuthSuccessHandler
```

**Result:**

After successful login the user is still redirected to previous page but again with path "j_spring_security_check", rather than desired "auth/welcome.jsp"

Logs show no error.

**My System.println results:**

```
Class  MyAuthSuccessHandler, grantedAuthority.getAuthority():ROLE_USER
Class  MyAuthSuccessHandler, request.getRequestURL():http://theda
llasapp_poc/j_spring_security_check
Class onAuthenticationSuccess  ,request.getContextPath(): /thedallasapp_poc
Class onAuthenticationSuccess  ,targetUrl: /auth/welcome
```

Thanks any help would be appreciated.